# "Солнце моё" — прописная или строчная буква в обращении?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, обращение

*Только не угасай, вечно сияй, моё  **Солнце**.

 Любимая, ты - моё хмельное счастье, моё  **солнце** и моя нежность.*

*И мой сын,  **Солнце** моё...

 Прощай,  **солнце** моё, мой несбывшийся...

 Не плачь, не крушися ты,  **солнце** моё!..*

Есть ли правила (или рекомендации), которые могут объяснить использование прописной или строчной буквы в устойчивом выражении (как обращение, одновременно)?
Или это прерогатива автора?

Вы просили ссылки:
1. [**Только не угасай, вечно сияй, моё  Солнце**](http://www.gl5.ru/in2nation-moe-solnce.html)
2. [**Любимая, ты - моё хмельное счастье, моё  солнце и моя нежность**](http://zedra.ru/confession-of-love/362-komplimenty-v-proze.html)
3. [**И мой сын,  Солнце моё**](https://www.proza.ru/2016/09/21/1409)
4. [**Прощай,  солнце моё, мой несбывшийся**](http://samlib.ru/j/jushmanowa_w_e/prol.shtml)
5. [**Не плачь, не крушися ты,  солнце моё!**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=cJPmh8enH-0C&pg=PA88&lpg=PA88&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5&source=bl&ots=h5VF0vEV--&sig=Vr82wiIYYNpIMPQWU6zma3Mczlo&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizkqvr2vXTAhXPbZoKHZlDAIMQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%82%D1%8B%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5&f=false)

Comment: Римма, "просили" - это, наверное, я. Но под ссылками тут обычно разумеют "кликабельную" ссылку на источник информации. Текстовые большого веса не имеют. Впрочем, не знаю, не мне решать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Устойчивые обращения вида**  "солнце  моё, радость моя, счастье моё" обычно пишутся со строчной буквы, использование прописной буквы —  чисто авторское решение, подчеркивающее  **особую важность слова.**

Это **общий принцип** выбора прописных и строчных букв (но он касается и обращений к конкретным лицам тоже). У Розенталя тема выглядит следующим образом: "**В особом стилистическом употреблении** с прописной буквы пишутся слова Родина, Отчизна, Человек, Вера, Надежда, Любовь, Разум, Мудрость, Центр и др."

[§28. Условные имена собственные](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/24.htm#%D0%B7_18)

**Примеры:**

Какие сны ты видела сейчас, **солнце мое**?» [Юлиан Семенов. Семнадцать мгновений весны (1968)].

Заждалась вас, **радость моя**... [А. П. Чехов. Вишневый сад (1904)]

Целую тебя, любимый! Будь здоров, будь осторожен, **счастье мое**! [Михаил Шишкин. Письмовник (2009) // «Знамя», 2010]

Answer (score 5):

Какую букву писать - прописную или строчную - решает автор высказывания. В слове Солнце прописная используется для выражения особо сильного чувства к человеку, трепетного к нему отношения, чуть ли не благоговения и преклонения.

Написанное со строчной буквы "солнце" в качестве обращения, определения или какого-то другого члена предложения воспринимается более спокойно, как выражение тёплого чувства, симпатии.

Comment: Ну, милый Демон, глупое мое Солнце, или уже не мое, не Демон, не Солнце? [Н. Н. Пунин. Письма А. А. Ахматовой (1929)]

Answer (score 2):

Из МАС:

> - *обычно чего.* **О том, что является источником или основой жизни чего-л. прекрасного.** *Солнце жизни моей, Россия, Укрепи на подвиг меня! Рыленков, Золотое облако зноя. — Вы знаете, — спросил Юнге, — что Гарибальди сказал о социализме?
>
>     — Социализм — это солнце будущего. Паустовский, Черное море.*
> - **О том, кто является предметом поклонения, любви.** *А вот Аннушка — вот это настоящее! — Она только одна и есть во всей его жизни сокровище, солнце, сияние. Гл. Успенский, Кой про что.*

Из "Орфографического словаря русского языка" Лопатина (РАН):

> **с**олнце, -а и *(центр Солнечной системы, астр.)* **С**олнце, -а; и на Солнце есть пятна.

Так, с точки зрения орфографии **во всех приведенных вами случаях верно написание со строчной буквы** (см. значение слова "солнце" в МАС). Если же речь идет о Солнце как астрономическом объекте (именно об астрономическом объекте Солнечной системы; если имеется в виду центральное тело других планетных систем, то верно ***с***олнце), правильным будет написание с прописной.

Comment: Простите, можно вопрос? Вы считаете, что нет разницы: "отдельное" солнце или солнце в устойчивом выражении.  А как же Лозичная и Ахматова?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова эта разница, на мой взгляд, не существенна: и там, и здесь написание должно быть со строчной буквы -- такова орфографическая норма. Другое дело, что авторы, в том числе и названные вами, могут с помощью прописной буквы подчеркивать высокую эмоциональную окраску. Это авторское решение, а не орфографическая норма. И Лозина, и Ахматова не устанавливают орфографических норм, вот что важно. (Слишком много "норм", но без этого не обойтись.)

Comment: А я ведь, собственно,  об ЭТОМ и спрашивала:  "...прерогатива автора?"

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова я бы не называл это так... Очень похожая ситуация с междометным выражением *слава богу*. Многие авторы пишут прописную *Б*, что противоречит орфографическим нормам. Но люди пишут, несмотря ни на что. Вот так же и здесь: есть норма, которая часто игнорируется в силу либо незнания этих самых правил, либо из каких-то личных убеждения (типа *я очень верю в Бога и не могу написать его название с маленькой буквы!* или *я так люблю своего внука/сына/пса, что не могу написать его обозначение с маленькой буквы!*). Орфография не допускает такого написание, но на практике — оно существует

Answer (score 2):

В общем, я думаю так. Екатерина Каштанова права. Автор решает. Надо только добавить, что если автор считает этот эпитет устойчивым выражением, то он и не требует заглавных букв. Если же по авторской мысли это некая претензия на собственное имя (типа прозвища, позывного или даже клички) то заглавная возможна.

К тому же "Солнце" само по себе в астрономическом значении пишется с заглавной. Если предположить, что тут именно Солнце = звезда, небесное тело (а почему нет?), то заглавная тем более оправдана.

Другое дело, что на практике авторы, как правило, предпочитают строчную.