# Прописная буква как средство индивидуализации

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, литература, редактура, текст

Где бы можно было прочитать об употреблении прописной буквы в целях индивидуализации, конкретизации предмета? Может, вы знаете и какие-то примеры на этот вопрос.

- Особенно интересны случаи не казённого употребления прописной буквы (по какому-то пункту правила, так как вряд ли и правила такие есть), а свободная, но обоснованная (!) авторская практика.
- Например, в художественной литературе это может выглядеть так. По правилам слово "ангел" пишется со строчной. Но автор делает ангела непосредственно действующим лицом и, чтобы индивидуализировать, конкретизировать именно этого ангела, выделить его из ряда вообще ангельских духов, он, автор, употребляет прописную букву: Тогда Ангел взял его за руку и сказал: "...".

Comment: http://orthographia.ru/go.php?url=http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=30#pp30 Можете прочитать здесь.

Comment: @Юлия Похожий вопрос (по смыслу): “Солнце моё” — прописная или строчная буква в обращении? https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430181/Солнце-моё-прописная-или-строчная-буква-в-обращении

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Индивидуализация предмета – это выделение его из ряда однородных предметов, когда нарицательное название лица/предмета становится его именем собственным. 
Например: собака Шарик, но Собака - персонаж из басни. Также ангелы – это нарицательное название, но конкретный Ангел уже пишется с прописной буквы.

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=83#pp83

§ 165. С прописной буквы пишутся нарицательные **слова, выступающие как названия персонажей в сказках, пьесах, баснях и некоторых других произведениях художественной литературы, фольклора,** напр.: Красная Шапочка,  Кот, Пёс, Сахар, Хлеб (персонажи «Синей птицы» М. Метерлинка); Весна, Леший (персонажи «Снегурочки» А. Островского), Городничий, Душечка, Левша, Некто в сером (литературные персонажи); проказница Мартышка, Осёл, Козёл да косолапый Мишка затеяли сыграть квартет (Крыл.).