# «Приедешь ко мне, Котик?» Или котик?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, ономастика, обращение

— Я заболела! Приедешь сегодня ко мне, Котик? [котик?]
— Нет, Лапонька! Ты же болеешь... Я к маме поеду! Выздоровеешь — позвони! [лапонька?]

*Котик* и *Лапонька* заменяют обращение к человеку по имени, поэтому их нужно с большой буквы писать?
Или же это что-то типа *милый, дорогая*? И тогда писать их нужно с маленькой буквы?
А может, и так можно, и так, в зависимости от того, что имеется в виду?

Comment: Когда-то я задавала похожий вопрос. "Щаз" попытаюсь вспомнить, найти... Вот, успела: "Солнце моё" — прописная или строчная буква в обращении? (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430181/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%91-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю так: если слова "котик" и "лапонька" являются просто ласковыми обращениями, мелькающими одновременно с другими подобными словечками (*зайчик, зверик, звездочка, рыбка, рыжик*...), то пишутся они со строчной буквы. Очень похоже на наш вариант.

*— Я заболела! Приедешь сегодня ко мне, **котик**?

— Нет, **лапонька**! Ты же болеешь... Я к маме поеду! Выздоровеешь — позвони!*

> — Паша! — крикнул Петров. — Почему ты называешь Марию ласточкой?
> Паша с готовностью забрался в кают-компанию и взял наполненный до половины небьющийся стакан с вином.
> — Я всех красивых женщин так называю. Чтобы не перепутать имена. И потом они все такие... ласточки. Так что, за вас!
> О. Михалевич. Форс-мажор

― А ты ― пупсик, ягодка, котик и солнышко, ― отвечал я Карине. [Иржи Грошек. Легкий завтрак в тени некрополя (1998)]

― Ничего, скоро приедем, ― успокоила его Маня и принялась дергать меня, ― **мусик**, нельзя ли побыстрей? [Дарья Донцова. Уха из золотой рыбки (2004)]

Если же эти словечки употребляются по отношению к одному человеку из года в год, становятся почти прозвищем, именем собственным, практически заменяющим имя человека, вот тогда, думаю, использование прописной возможно. Как в том старом анекдоте.

— Ты нам, Солнышко, еще пива не принесешь?..
—  Вы так давно женаты, а ты ей — Солнышко.
—  Да я за столько лет просто забыл, как ее зовут.

На веранду выбежала **Мусик**, тонко разбиравшаяся в интонациях мужа. [Илья Ильф, Евгений Петров. Двенадцать стульев (1927)]

Иногда такие ласковые прозвища возникают от имени, например: Костя — Костян, Кося, Котя, Котик, Котяра. Иногда — от внешнего облика, особенного поведения, говора.
В нашей семье, например, есть Ёжик и Карамель (в телефоне — *Jozik, Karamell*).