# Вы самая красивая на земле/Земле

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, ономастика

Как правильно?

*Лео вот считает, что Вы самая красивая за земле/Земле.

На земле/Земле много зарыто кладов.

До Луны/луны далеко лететь.

Мы посмотрели когда на луну/Луну, увидели, что она громоздкая была.

На земле/Земле нет девушки красивее, чем Вы, мэм.*

Comment: Лео, вопросы на эту тему обсуждались на форуме много раз, в них нет ничего нового. Вы можете сами решить ваши задачи.  Дайте, пожалуйста, свой ответ.

Comment: Я за вопрос плюс поставлю. В первых двух действительно интересно. А в двух прследних обязательна прописная буква, поскольку Луна рассматривается как астрономический объект.

Comment: Я не вижу ничего проблемного. Лео  сам ответит на свой вопрос, у него достаточная репутация для этого.  Обычные типовые задачки. Справочник ему в помощь.

Comment: Вообще-то, это не так легко, как вы, Шерон, утверждаете: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%9D%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5+%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%2C+%D0%9D%D0%B0+%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5+%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=ru-2019&smoothing=3.

Comment: Легче, чем вы думаете.  А вот ответик вам дали весьма заурядный и проблему раскрывающий недостаточно. Но вы, как всегда, торопитесь с приемкой. Ладно, ребята.  Задавайте дальше свои спам-вопросы, получайте спам-ответы.  Других тем  за этими спамиками не видно. Не хочется время тратить, потому что без толку.  А вы, Лео, про слово на М не забывайте. Нет ничего хуже в жизни, если кто-то вас лично так назовет.

Comment: Мы земле/Земле нет дувушки красивее, чем Вы, мэм. - вот это я не могу понять, что нацарапано, мяу.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Про обращение "Солнце моё" я задавала вопрос (давно, когда только-только появилась на сайте). Посмотрите, если есть желание. Там тоже есть *достойные* объяснения. (https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430181/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%86%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%91-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, *Земля* и *Луна* могут писаться с большой, только если они рассматриваются как астрономические термины.

В первых двух случаях есть намек на астрономию? Нет! Значит, пишем со строчной:

*Лео вот считает, что Вы самая красивая за земле*;

*На земле много зарыто кладов*.

Здесь слово *земля* употреблено в значении 1.2.:

> 1.2.
> Место жизни и деятельности людей.
> Сколько обидного на земле! * Слухом земля полнится Посл..
>
> - Все говорят: нет правды на земле Пушкин.
>   З. держится на ком-л. о лучших представителях народа; о тех, кто много и хорошо работает.

А в следующих двух *Луна* как раз рассматривается как астрономический объект, а не как месяц в небе в повседневной жизни.

*До Луны далеко лететь*;

*Мы посмотрели когда на Луну, увидели, что она громоздкая была*.

Хотя в случае 2.2. возможно и употребление в значении *месяц* (тогда бы писалось с маленькой буквы).

Два словаря Грамоты: *[Земля](https://gramota.ru/meta/zemlya)*, *[Луна](https://gramota.ru/meta/luna)*.

Comment: А что в этом вопросе было проблемного и интересного лично для вас? Над чем вам пришлось подумать, так сказать, в чем были сомнения? И почему Лео так и не смог сам дать ответ, а вы стали ему помогать. Сведения довольно заурядные, 5-6 класс примерно.

Answer (score 3):

```
На мой взгляд, Земля и Луна могут писаться с большой, только 
если они рассматриваются как астрономические термины.
```

Нет, не только. Есть еще **высокая поэзия**, есть **фантастика**, где все возможно. Много чего есть за пределами **приземленных** душ.

Владимир Высоцкий

**Песня о Земле**

Кто сказал: «Всё сгорело дотла,
Больше в землю не бросите семя!»?
Кто сказал, что **Земля** умерла?
Нет, она затаилась на время.

Материнства не взять у **Земли**,
Не отнять, как не вычерпать моря.
Кто поверил, что **Землю** сожгли?
Нет, она почернела от горя.

Как разрезы, траншеи легли,
И воронки, как раны, зияют.
Обнажённые нервы **Земли**
Неземное страдание знают.

Она вынесет всё, переждёт,
Не записывай **Землю** в калеки!
Кто сказал, что **Земля** не поёт,
Что она замолчала навеки?!

Нет! Звенит она, стоны глуша,
Изо всех своих ран, из отдушин,
Ведь **Земля** — это наша душа,
Сапогами не вытоптать душу!

Кто сказал, что **Земля** умерла?
Нет, она затаилась на время.

Comment: Факультативное озаглавливание слова, что ль?

Comment: Говорю же, высокая поэзия.  Любое слово в высоком значении может писаться с прописной буквы, об этом и в справочниках говорится. Удивительно, что отвечающий вам об этом не рассказал.  Наспех состряпанный ответ, некогда было.

Comment: Мне *показалось*, что такое оформление лучше воспринимается (https://chitaemstihi.ru/vladimir-vysotskij/pesnya-o-zemle/). Поэтому и перераспределила. И выделила ещё одну "Землю".

Comment: Кстати, почему у ВВС Земля с большой буквы? Что такое "высокое значение"?

Comment: @Буратино   О ВЫСОКОМ ЗНАЧЕНИИ   ПАС § 203.    http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=81#pp81  С прописной буквы могут писаться некоторые нарицательные существительные в контекстах, где им приписывается особый высокий смысл: Родина, Отечество, Отчизна, Свобода, Добро, Честь, Человек, Учитель, Мастер и т. п.  Розенталь  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=13#pp13

Comment: РОЗЕНТАЛЬ     http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=13#pp13   § 26. Условные имена собственные  2. В особом стилистическом употреблении с прописной буквы пишутся слова Родина, Отчизна, Человек и др.

Comment: Ну я не нашёл там "о высоком значении" строчек. Но нашёл: прописная буква служит для выделения отдельных слов независимо от строения текста.

Comment: @Буратино Не понимаю вас. Слово Земля использовано в особом стилистическом употреблении. Как слово Родина, например. Возможны оба варианта.  У вас стихотворение не вызывает "высоких чувств"?

Comment: Я думаю, употребление Земля с большой буквы Высоцким, это во многом дань моде и русскому космизму, ставшему массово популярным после полёта Гагарина 1961 года, а песня 1969. Земля в смысле планета, то есть, однако живая планета и сочетающая в себе мать-сыру землю тоже.

Comment: Это всего лишь  "место жизни и деятельности людей"?  Какой там Гагарин! Вот именно что живая планета, а не место, куда клад можно зарыть.  А Мать-земля с прописной пишете.

Comment: @Sharon спор о семантике может быть бесконечным, если вы не опираетесь на какие-то грамматические принципы при написании. Принцип какой? мать - сыра земля вообще всё со строчной надо по классике, я поправил.

Comment: Не, не буду приводить. Есть два варианта и точка. Можете писать со строчной, никто вас не обязывает. И Высоцкого вы не понимаете. Его поэзия вне времени, а вы к покорению космоса ее привязали. О чем же нам говорить?

Comment: @Sharon а что плохого в том, что я привязал к культурно-историческому событию определённую тенденцию в грамматике? "Его поэзия вне времени" - в моём понимании, одно другому не мешает, а как раз наоборот, дополняет.

Comment: @Sharon ну покорение космоса, чем не подвиг, достойный своего Гомера? Поэт, конечно, аутист, ко всему суетному и временному, но это явно не рядовое событие, а чудо.

Comment: По поводу Гомера не знаю, это к Пушкину. Поэт сам выбирает тему творчества, толпа ему не указ.  И грамматики в прописных буквах не вижу, Правила, семантика, но только не грамматика.  Зачем смешивать-перемешивать.

Comment: @Sharon а я думаю иначе, я думаю, что русский - синтетический язык, то есть сочетает в себе различные грамматические нормы, однако видоизменяя из под собственную. То есть включает и присваивает, поедает, как живой организм. При этом он называется синтетический, но по факту он не является синтетическим, так как сохраняет и логику, и аналитику. То есть он живой, как Даль его определил и наделён свойствами живого. Вот у вас есть неведомый вопрос, почему пишется тут так, а тут сяк - ну давайте осознаем, какую грамматику русский язык тут ест.

Comment: Давайте осознаем, только тогда уж на равных, а не "вы мне давайте объясните". И давайте как в шахматах: я начинаю партию – и выигрываю.  И чтобы без многословия: мой ход, ваш ход.  Идет?  Только немного позднее, сейчас времени нет.  Воскресенье же, приемный день! Да и уйти надо с этого места на поле ответа.  Давайте так. Я задам вопрос, а вы дадите ответ. А там и поговорим. Идет?

Comment: @Sharon не факт, что дам исчерпывающий ответ, но попробовать можно.

Comment: ОК, тогда до встречи.

Comment: @Sharon удалили вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на комментарий

```
  Давайте так. Я задам вопрос, а вы дадите ответ. А там и 
  поговорим. Идет?  

  Не факт, что дам исчерпывающий ответ, но попробовать 
  можно. 

  ОК, тогда до встречи.  

  @Sharon удалили вопрос?
```

Да, удалила, и сейчас объясню **причину.**

Эта тема интересна тем, что **частных** правил здесь очень много, просто энциклопедия частных решений, так что трудно найти исходную **точку отсчета**. У меня же есть **методика решения** для любого орфографического правила: указать причину орфограммы, обозначить общее решение, а потом уже переходить к решениям частным.

Тему я изучала **по Розенталю**, но  в ПАС увидела некоторое созвучие своему подходу: там хотя бы обозначили **выделительную  функцию прописных букв.** Поэтому первый мой вопрос был по выделительной функции.

Однако подобное мышление было настолько **чуждо** окружающим, что они аккуратно обходили вопрос стороной, в принципе не понимая такого «прикола».  Он вызывал еще больше недоумения, чем, к примеру, мой интонационный анализ. Если бы я написала свой вопрос по-китайски, эффект был бы тот же самый. Поэтому я убрала **«китайский» вопрос**.

Вы ведь тоже не стали на него отвечать, хотя на форуме присутствовали. Я сделала вывод, что вопрос **непонятен** и вам тоже.

Если перефразировать слова известной песни, то можно сказать так:  «Это могло стать **интересной дискуссией**, но так и не стало». История не знает сослагательного наклонения)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150504/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.